# Can't fetch supported time zones in Iana format

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Trying to fetch supported time zones in Iana format from MS Graph using this code

```
var timeZones = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Outlook
    .SupportedTimeZones(TimeZoneStandard.Iana)
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

I get this error

`The parameter 'TimeZoneStandard=Iana' is not in scope.`

Making the same call without the TimeZoneStandard.Iana parameter succceeds. Is TimeZoneStandard.Iana not supported?

Answer (score -1):

Parameter needs to be correctly given as 
`(microsoft.graph.timeZoneStandard'Iana')` as shown in below image.

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwy99.png)

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-supportedtimezones?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the code isn't valid C# (as the comment at the bottom of the document you refer to also states).